# Weblogic : Unable to ping server at localhost:7001

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c, intellij-plugin

I am using WebLogic as an application server in IntelliJ. But after debugging and entering the username, this error appears and disconnects from the server Application:
"Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason: Unable to ping server at localhost:7001".

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I changed the port and the problem disappeared.